# convergent almost surly and infinite ofen

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Prove that $X_n \to 0$ a.e if and only if for all $\epsilon>0$ $P(|X_n|>\epsilon\ i.o)  = P(\limsup_n \{|X_n|>\epsilon\}) = 0$

My attempt:

since for probability measure $P(X) = 1<\infty$ hence it's bounded.So we can use inverse Fatou's which shows that $P(\limsup_n \{|X_n|>\epsilon\}) = 0 \ge \lim_n P(\{|X_n|>\epsilon\})  = 0$.

For the converse direction we can use Borel Cantelli lemma

Is my proof correct?

For the last result below:

if we have a $\omega \in \limsup E_n $ with $E_n = \{|X_n|>\epsilon\}$  then we have for any $n$ exist a $k>n$ with $|X_k|>\epsilon$.then $g_n = \sup_{k\ge n}|X_k| >\epsilon$ hence we have $\limsup_n|X_n|\ge\epsilon$.

For the converse direction if $\omega \in \{\limsup|X_n|>\epsilon\}$ then there is a subsequence that $|X_{n_j}|>\epsilon$,which impies there are infinite term holds $|X_n|>\epsilon$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not correct. How do you apply Borel Cantelli Lemma here?

Let $A_k =\{\lim \sup |X_n| >\frac  1 k\}$. Then $$P(\{\lim \sup |X_n| >\epsilon) =0$$ for every $\epsilon >0$ iff $$P(A_k)=0$$ for  ever $k$ iff $$P(\cup_k  A_k)=0$$.

This is so iff there is probability $1$ that for every $k$ we can find $n_k$ with $$|X_n| \leq \frac  1k$$ for  $n \geq n_k$ iff $X_n \to 0 $ almost surely.

Also note that $|X_n| >\epsilon$ i.o. implies $\lim \sup |X_n| \geq \epsilon$ and $\lim \sup |X_n| >\epsilon$ implies that $|X_n| >\epsilon$ i.o.

Comment: If we have $X_n \to 0$ a.e,then denote $E_n = \{|X_n|>\epsilon\}$  we have a sequence $E_n$ with $P(E_n)<\frac{1}{2^n}$ which implies sum of them is bounded hence we have $P(E_n\ i.o) = 0$

Comment: @yi_li No, that is not valid. Why is $P(E_n) <\frac  1{2^n}$?

Comment: Since $X_n \to 0$ a.e. hence the set $\mu\{x:|X_n|>\epsilon\} \to 0$?

Comment: If $a_n \to 0$ can you say $a_n <\frac 1 {2^{n}}$?. Take $a_n =\frac 2 {2^{n}}$ to see that this is  not true.

Comment: Can you elaborate the first iff? I can't get this one. another question is $P(|X_n|>\epsilon\ i.o) = P(\limsup\{|X_n|>\epsilon\})$ or $= P(\{\limsup |X_n| > \epsilon\})$

Comment: @yi_li Use the fact that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exist $k$ with $\frac  1 k <\epsilon$ and for every $k$ there exists $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon <\frac  1k$.

Comment: Is there difference between $\{\lim \sup |X_n| >\epsilon\}  $ and $ \limsup\{|X_n|>\epsilon\} $?

Comment: There is very minor difference between the two. I have explaned that in the last part of my answer. [The difference is between strict inequality and loose inequality].

Comment: I got it, thanks for you help,the key point here is we can convert arbitrary  $\epsilon$ to countable $\frac{1}{k}$,I have proved the last result on the post above is my proof correct?